# Sql Server 2012. Как решить проблему с отсутствием прав доступа?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ado.net

Имеется база данных на SQL Server 2012. В базе данных создан пользователь таким образом:

```sql
CREATE LOGIN MyUser1
    WITH PASSWORD = '123';
USE Банк;
GO
CREATE USER MyUser1 FOR LOGIN MyUser1;
GO
```

К базе данных я подключаюсь из приложения на C#, с помощью SqlConnection, явно указывая пароль и логин в строке подключения. 
В приложении я попытался реализовать возможность создания нового пользователя таким образом:

```
private void CommandExecute(String command) 
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = Connection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = command;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}

CommandExecute("CREATE LOGIN " + Login + " WITH PASSWORD = '" + Password + "';");
CommandExecute(" CREATE USER " + Login + " FOR LOGIN " + Login + ";");
CommandExecute("INSERT INTO Client(Client.FullName,Client.PhoneNumber,Client.Address,Client.Login)VALUES('" + FullName + "','" + Phone + "','" + Address + "','" + Login + "')");
```

Вся суть этого кода, просто выполнение первого приведенного запроса на стороне клиента. Во время выполнения данного кода, выпадает ошибка выполнения, утверждающая что данный пользователь(под которым был осуществлен вход) не имеет разрешения на выполнения этой операции. Я так понимаю что проблема решается настройкой на стороне сервера, я пробовал решить ее, но ничего не вышло. Просветите меня как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Проблема, я так понял, что у пользователя, под которым вы авторизуетесь на сервере, недостаточно прав для создания новых пользователей и вы не знаете как эти права ему предоставить? Что вы хотите увидеть в ответе? скрипт который добавляет прав пользователю? или гайд по тому как через Managment studio добавить прав пользователю?

Comment: Любой способ который решит данную проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После регистрации пользователя надо выдать ему разрешения. 
В T-SQL делается с помощью [GRANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178569(v=sql.120).aspx).

Для `CREATE USER` требуется permission `ALTER ANY USER`.

Comment: Вы не знаете какое разрешение необходимо добавить чтобы пользователь мог добавлять новых пользователей?

Comment: добавил в ответ